# Filter an element in an object in an array in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling to find the index of the array that has `id === 3`.

```
const id = 3;
const bigList = [
  [
    { id: "1", foo: "a" },
    { id: "2", foo: "b" }
  ],
  [
    { id: "3", foo: "c" },
    { id: "4", foo: "d" }
  ],
  [
    { id: "5", foo: "e" },
    { id: "6", foo: "f" }
  ]
];
```

I tried this to filter out that array.

```
const filteredList = bigList.filter(list => list.filter(item => item.id === id))
```

But it was wrong.

I really appreciate if you show me how it works. Thanks!

Comment: You want just one `index` or all the matched elements in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findIndex` with a `some()`. Also notice that `id` variable is number but property of the object is a string

```js
const id = 3;
const bigList = [
  [
    { id: "1", foo: "a" },
    { id: "2", foo: "b" }
  ],
  [
    { id: "3", foo: "c" },
    { id: "4", foo: "d" }
  ],
  [
    { id: "5", foo: "e" },
    { id: "6", foo: "f" }
  ]
];

const res = bigList.findIndex(x => x.some(y => y.id === id.toString()));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're really close.

One way to do it is this,

`bigList.filter(list => list.filter(item => item.id === "3").length !== 0);`

If you look at the documentation of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you'll see that it returns a **new array**. So, the result of your inner filter would yield an array that needs to be evaluated to a true or false condition.

One way to do that is to check the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `some` to check if the list has the element with `id` of 3, and remember to cast the `id` to string before compare

```js
const id = 3;
const bigList = [
  [
    { id: "1", foo: "a" },
    { id: "2", foo: "b" },
  ],
  [
    { id: "3", foo: "c" },
    { id: "4", foo: "d" },
  ],
  [
    { id: "5", foo: "e" },
    { id: "6", foo: "f" },
  ],
];

const filteredList = bigList.filter((list) =>
  list.some((item) => Number(item.id) === id)
);

console.log(filteredList);
```

or you could use [Abstract Equality Comparison (`==`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) to compare, then item.id will be coerced to number

```js
const id = 3;
const bigList = [
  [
    { id: "1", foo: "a" },
    { id: "2", foo: "b" },
  ],
  [
    { id: "3", foo: "c" },
    { id: "4", foo: "d" },
  ],
  [
    { id: "5", foo: "e" },
    { id: "6", foo: "f" },
  ],
];

const filteredList = bigList.filter((list) =>
  list.some((item) => item.id == id)
);

console.log(filteredList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `filter` but only once so that inside it you can control the return value, like this:

```
console.log(bigList.filter((el) => {
    var returnVal = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
        if (el[j].id == 3) {
            returnVal = true;
            break;
        }
        else { returnVal = false; }
    }
    return returnVal;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten your array using `array#flat` and then filter it based on `searchId`.

```js
const searchId = 3,
      bigList = [ [ { id: "1", foo: "a" }, { id: "2", foo: "b" } ], [ { id: "3", foo: "c" }, { id: "4", foo: "d" } ], [ { id: "5", foo: "e" }, { id: "6", foo: "f" } ] ],
      result = bigList
          .flat()
          .filter(({id }) => id === String(searchId));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use findIndex method to find the index of the array containing id = 3.

```
bigList.findIndex((item) => (item.findIndex(el => el.id === id.toString())) > -1)
```